# Does anyone know if Apple iTunes will accept a single page app that is a browser loading a website

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I have am loading a responsive website in a wrapper, my app is just a browser screen loading my live website. I have read that Apple iTunes does not allow apps that connect to external urls (I doubt that is true).

Does anyone know if Apple iTunes will approve this type of app?
 [image]

Comment: I don't think so. Apple won't review the content of your app, just the code and a UIWebView looks normally more like a mellicious app than an app which could have any advantages

Answer (score 3):

[Common App Rejections](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/)

> Web clippings, content aggregators, or a collections of links
>
> Your app should be engaging and useful, and make the most of the
>   features unique to iOS. Websites served in an iOS app, web content
>   that is not formatted for iOS, and limited web interactions do not
>   make a quality app.

Answer (score 2):

From the official [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> **2.12** Apps that are not very useful, unique, are simply web sites bundled as Apps, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected

---

As Jason mentioned from the [Common App Rejections](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/rejections/):

> **Web clippings, content aggregators, or a collections of links**
>
> Your app should be engaging and useful, and make the most of the features unique to iOS. Websites served in an iOS app, web content that is not formatted for iOS, and limited web interactions do not make a quality app.

---

I remember that an app of me was approved, even though it was just a website bundled as an app. The only difference was, that there was a special notification, if the user lost network connection or wasn't connected at all. I believe it could get approved if you add at least a little bit code to it.

---

If you can bundle your website and deliver it offline, your app should get approved. Have a look at [Cordova](https://cordova.apache.org), which exactly does this.